# Books/links to explain Jquery& Javascript events captured in ASP.NET C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Jquery / Javascript / AJAX is becoming more popular now it seems.  I will want to better understand how to use this functionality in C#.

**Are there any links or books you can point me to that teaches javascript from a web C# perspective?**
Not just simple statements like:
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm_delete();");

More like javascript Event A (can be any type of event) gets fired.  C# event handler captures Event A - then code behind executes.  Do I use delegates, WebHandler, WebMethod, IHttpHandler?

I know ASP.NET C# and Javascript are two very different things, but I can't ignore all the good jquery stuff available and I want to use it all in my c# code.
I just want to better understand the very basics so I can play with writting javascript and don't need to start asking urgent/simple questions.

BTW. I'm using VS2008.  Will VS2012 integrate javascript better?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are many links some of them

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.in/2012/01/jquery-ajax-examples-by-calling-aspnet.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17203/Using-jQuery-for-AJAX-in-ASP-NET

http://www.csharpbydesign.com/2008/06/aspnet-ajax-and-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks for the links!  This should keep me busy for a while  :D